# What is the difference between build, buildU & buildSpec in Scalajs-react?

Tags: scalajs-react

Can someone please explain the difference between the functions `build`, `buildU` and `buildSpec` for React components in scalajs-react and when to use one over the other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/USAGE.md

> Call `build` (or `buildU`) and when it compiles you will have a React component. […] If your props type is `Unit`, use `buildU` instead to be able to instantiate your component with having to pass `()` as a constructor argument.

As for `buildSpec`, you can follow the types if you're interested but isn't mentioned because as @nafg says above, it's a low-level method that isn't relevant unless you already know what a "spec" is in the React world and you're doing something complicated with it. For what a React spec is, you can inspect the code and/or read about it in the React docs. Otherwise if you just want to create Scala React components, you only need to follow the instructions and examples and use `build{,U}`.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure myself but it seems:

- `build` produces a scala component function that takes an instance of your props type as a parameter
- `buildU` is for when your props type is `Unit` (that's what the *U* stands for), i.e., you don't need any props object, so you can use the component without providing a props object.
- `buildSpec` I'm less clear about, but it returns an instance of `ReactComponentSpec` which has a `js.native` annotation, so I suspect it somehow gives you lower-level access to the React object.